# Gmail apps script: Execute a function upon reply

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is there a way to run code as a result of replying to a message, like a callback handler? I would like to automatically remove a label from a message upon manually replying.

Comment: I believe you could reply to a message through a Gmail Addon and at the same time run other code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Gmail API Push Notifications, Cloud Pubsub API and a GAS Web App as an HTTP endpoint/Webhook (as of late 2020, Cloud Pubsub no longer requires domain verification for Http endpoints so GAS WebApps are once again a viable option).

The following resources should be enough to get you started:

- Gmail API

  - [Push Notification Guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)
  - [Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest)
  - [Spencer Easton's Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjHp9_NAEJo) (some parts of the tutorial are no longer relevant since domain verification is not necessary anymore but its a good jumping off point to start learning about the process)
- Cloud Pubsub API

  - [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/concepts)
  - [Youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIivdWyY5sqKwVLe4BLJ-vlh9r9zCdOse)
- GAS WebApp

  - [Documentation/Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)